# DataContext Binding broken after setting a different instance of the "same" (Equals()) object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I sometimes use a DataContext binding on UserControls and Panels when all the child controls show data from the same object. But if I set that property to a new instance of of an object where the two objects are Equal (as in their Equals method returns true), the controls don't rebind to the new object. They seem to continue to display and update the data from the previous object.

In the example below, the CurrentDeal property is a Deal object which implements a custom Equals method that returns true when the two Deals have the same unique database identifier. When setting CurrentDeal, the setter does not check equality. It always sets the value and raises a PropertyChanged event.

```xml
<Grid DataContext="{Binding CurrentDeal}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay"} />
</Grid>
```

```cs
private Deal _currentDeal;
public Deal CurrentDeal
{
    get { return _currentDeal; }
    set
    {
        _currentDeal = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentDeal));
    }
}
```

If I set a completely different Deal, then the textbox shows the new Deal's Price, and updating the value in the text box updates the Price on the new Deal as expected.

But if I set it to a newer instance of the "same" Deal (same in that their Equals methods return true), then the text box continues to show the old value (the Price may have changed since the last time this Deal was displayed). Also, changing the value in the text box doesn't update the new Deal's Price (I haven't tested if it updates the old Deal's Price, but I'm guessing that's what's happening).

But, if I were to do this instead, everything works as expected.

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding CurrentDeal.Price, Mode=TwoWay"} />
</Grid>
```

Obviously, if I could do that everywhere I would, but my problem comes when using reusable UserControls. I have to set the DataContext if a UserControl is to be bound to the same object but in different View/View Models.

I also can't just refresh the old entity because these are Entity Framework entities from different contexts. This came about when switching towards a "new context for every request" solution, rather than an "each VM gets its own context" solution.

I'm honestly not really sure what my question is... this seems like a bug in the DataContext binding. I don't think it should be taking equality into account. When a PropertyChanged event is fired on the property, it should always bind to the current data, right?

But can anyone see if I'm missing something here? Anyone ever had to deal with this before?

Comment: It's not a good idea to bind directly to model objects. It is usual to copy values from an EF object into a VM which is then bound. And back again. This way your vm can have all your validation code, isdirty, inotifypropertychanged etc and your EF class remains un polluted. And. Your problem would then go away because you could either new up a new viewmodel when you get a logical change to your deal OR set properties in that deal's viewmodel to the new values and they would raise propertychanged.

Comment: "*When a PropertyChanged event is fired on the property, it should always bind to the current data, right*? Only if it considers the new object to to differ from the old one which it apparently doesn't given your implementation of `Equals`. The solution to your issue would be to bind to a view model that doesn't implement `Equals` like this.

Comment: This already is in a View Model. CurrentDeal is in a View Model. My point is that I have a handful of reusable UserControls that really only need to bind to an EF object. All business logic, validation, etc. is done in the View Model. But multiple View Models can have Deals and I want to display the Deal with the same UserControl in multiple Views/View Models. All this User Control has is input fields for the Deal's properties.

I understand I can just wrap the Deal in a wrapper VM, but it just seems crazy to me.

Comment: Again, I'm not really sure what I'm asking here... I understand it's a weird use case. I honestly just found it weird that a binding would check equality when a PropertyChanged event is fired.